# Memory footprint of member variables in Java class

Tags: java

I am trying to understand the memory footprint of a java class instrumented by various data members within the class. I found some background material going through this article :

http://java-performance.info/overview-of-memory-saving-techniques-java/

Based on this, my understanding is that if I have a class with only a single array of primitive type, the array declaration itself should consume 12 bytes. Class header should take another 12 bytes. The total memory footprint of an object of type SingleArray will be 24 bytes.

```
public class SingleArray {
    int[] array1;
}
```

Using object instrumentation, I found that an object of SingleArray indeed consumes 24 bytes without any data. In that regard, object of class DoubleArray should consume 40 bytes (considering padding):

```
public class DoubleArray {
    int[] array1;
    long[] array2;
}
```

But an object of type DoubleArray seem to also consume 24 bytes. I am confused. What am I missing?

Comment: Uh, what?  The array reference will take four bytes; if you actually put an array in there, the array header will take 12 bytes plus the contents of the array.  It looks like you're running into padding where objects are rounded up to a multiple of 8 bytes.  It's also not clear what environment you're running this in, which matters rather a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, whatever the blog entry says, seeing is believing. I downloaded jol-cli-0.3.2-full.jar from http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jol/ and applied it to your classes with

```
java -jar jol-cli-0.3.2-full.jar internals -cp bin x.SingleArray
```

It provides the following output for SingleArray on a Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode):

```
 OFFSET  SIZE  TYPE DESCRIPTION     
      0     4       (object header) 
      4     4       (object header) 
      8     4       (object header) 
     12     4 int[] SingleArray.array1
Instance size: 16 bytes (reported by Instrumentation API)
Space losses: 0 bytes internal + 0 bytes external = 0 bytes total
```

And for DoubleArray:

```
 OFFSET  SIZE   TYPE DESCRIPTION                    VALUE
      0     4        (object header)
      4     4        (object header)
      8     4        (object header)
     12     4  int[] DoubleArray.array1
     16     4 long[] DoubleArray.array2
     20     4        (loss due to the next object alignment)
Instance size: 24 bytes (reported by Instrumentation API)
Space losses: 0 bytes internal + 4 bytes external = 4 bytes total
```

Not sure which instrumentation you used. And it also depends on the VM in use as well as the memory model.

1) My hunch is that the memory used by the array where it is stored is 12 bytes minimum. But within SingleArray, only a pointer is stored.

2) Depending on the memory model, the pointer may be 4 or 8 bytes. Even on a 64bit machine, the pointers may be just 32bit. See [Compressed Oops](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/performance-enhancements-7.html).

Comment: Unless you have a heap of over 32 GB, your references are likely to be 32-bit. i.e. most JVMs.

Answer (score 1):

To start with a correction, `array declaration` and `Class header` don't consume memory, allocated objects do.

How much memory do instances of `SingleArray` and `DoubleArray` consume? In the end this depends on the JVM runtime, but today these are the most likely numbers:

an instance of `SingleArray`: 16 bytes

- 8 bytes for the object
- 4 bytes for the reference to member `array1`
- 4 bytes for padding to get a multiple of 8 bytes

an instance of `DoubleArray`: 16 bytes

- 8 bytes for the object
- 4 bytes for the reference to member `array1`
- 4 bytes for the reference to member `array2`
- 0 bytes for padding to get a multiple of 8 bytes

Comment: Object headers use 8 bytes on 32-bit JVMs and 12 bytes on 64-bit JVMs by default.

Comment: @PeterLawrey thank you, good to know - doing my measurements on a 32 bit machine using jamm

Comment: It is good to see the 32-bit JVM is not dead and it still gets used.